# PHP Return Loop Result

Tags: php, loops, return

I am new to the world of coding as well as PHP and am wondering how I can use `return` when looping. For example I would like to return/display 1-10 however not use echo.

```
$start = 1;
$end = 11;

for($start; $start < $end; $start=$start+1) {

echo $start; //how can I use return?

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return something? And to where?

Comment: More interesting: Where do you want to return something from? I dont see any function. And if you want to display something, whats the matter with `echo`?

Comment: @Dogbert/KingCrunch - The reason I would like to return something is because I wish to return the results into another function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `return` will exit the function, so if you put `return` in a loop, the loop will only do one iteration (until the `return` statement).

You can collect all the values in an [**array**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and return the array:

```
function myFunction() {
    $start = 1;
    $end = 11;
    $values = array();

    for($start; $start < $end; $start=$start+1) {
       $values[] = $start;
    }

    return $values;
}
```

That said, a function generating consecutive numbers already exists: [**`range()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

Comment: Thanks. The reason I ask is if I wish to return the values of one function into another. Veryhelpful answer. Didn't think we could feed the values into an array.

Answer (score 2):

`return` is for sending the results of a function call back to the function or script that called it. It's the opposite of passing parameters to a function.

What you're doing is looping over a variable in the same scope, so `return` is not needed. Printing is done via `echo` or `print`. However, you may choose to build a value in that loop and print that once the loop is completed.

Additionally, if you're in a loop and you want to stop that loop immediately, use `break`; and if you want to skip the iteration you're on and go to the next one, use `continue`.

Here's [some additional reading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

---

More clarification on `continue`. Say, for whatever reason, we don't want to do anything when `$i` is `6`:

```
$start = 1;
$end = 11;

for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) 
// changed this to iterate over $i for readability/clarity
{
    if ($start == 6)
    {
        // essentially, continue just skips this iteration of 
        // the loop, goes back to the top, iterates $i based on 
        // that third parameter in the for() declaration, and 
        // continues on.

        continue;
    }


    echo $start; //how can I use return?
}

// output: 1234578910
```

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about `continue`. How would I use that in the example of my code?

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
function foobar()
{   
   $output = '';
   for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ )
   {
      $output .= $i;
   }
   return $output
}

echo foobar();
```

Comment: Thanks. Very simple solution. I like it. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by defining a variable you want to `return` inside and outside the loop with `.=`.

Here is a working example:

```
function my_function() {

// I am the variable to be return-ed
$k = "My World<br/>";

for ($z=1; $z<=3; $z++) {
$v = 'Here'.$z;

// I am the same variable but I am going inside the loop
$k .= $v . "<br/>";
}

//I am not always important to be here!
$k .= "Is Awesome";

// This is the show time..
return $k;

} 

my_function();
```

**Output:**

```
My World
Here1
Here2
Here3
Is Awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will end the function that you are currently in. The scenario you have given us is not a good scenario to use the return function.

The example below will do the same as your code, but uses a function as well as your for loop. Hope this answeres your question.

```
$start = 11;
$end = 20;

for($start; $start <= $end; $start++){
     echo calculateValue($start);
}

function calculateValue($value){
    return $value - 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not giving a very good scenario. I am wanting to learn how to return the values of a function into another.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function loop_kec($ar_kec) {
        $total_data = count($ar_kec) - 1;
        //$return_kec = array();
        for ($e = 0; $e < $total_data; $e++) {
            $return_kec .= 'kecamatan = ' . "'$ar_kec[$e]'" . ' or ';
        }
        $return_kec .= 'kecamatan = ' . "'$ar_kec[$total_data]'";
        return $return_kec;
    }
```